# installing ubuntu on windows 8 ubuntu doesn't load

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 12.4 on computer with previously installed windows 8. When I reboot the system I have two options to choose from when I select Ubuntu it give me a black page that says that windows is damaged and I have to repair it. It says that there are missing files in Ubuntu directory.Did I downloaded the correct Ubuntu?  I selected for the option Other when asked what kind of operational system I am running - there was no option window8.

Answer (score 0):

Many users trying to dual boot windows and ubuntu are running into issues with Secure Boot. This might be your problem as well - start with [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341168/installing-13-04-with-windows-8-secure-boot-failed) and see if that solves your problem. Otherwise posting the errors as they are might provide more insight on the problem.